# What are seams and creases and how to use them

Tags: uv

I want to know what is seam and crease in Blender and why do we need them and also how to use them?

Comment: Hi! Consider asking only 1 question per post. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello :). Blender manual covers both [Seams](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/uv/unwrapping/seams.html) and [Creases](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#edge-crease).